# XAML: correct way of accessing buttons embedded inside of a datagrid and changing properties programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

so for example i have this xaml code

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Width="50" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button x:Name="PlayButton" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Visibility="Visible"
                    Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="OnPlayButtonClicked"
                    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindow}">
                <Rectangle Width="20"
                           Height="20">
                    <!--<Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="Resources/playIcon.png"  Name="Image"></Image>-->
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                                     Visual="{StaticResource appbar_control_play}" />
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <!--<Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="Resources/playIcon.png"  Name="Image"></Image>-->
            </Button>

            <Button x:Name="PauseButton" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Visibility="Hidden"
                    Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="OnPauseButtonClicked"
                    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindow}">
                <Rectangle Width="20"
                           Height="20">
                    <!--<Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="Resources/playIcon.png"  Name="Image"></Image>-->
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                                     Visual="{StaticResource appbar_control_pause}" />
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <!--<Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="Resources/playIcon.png"  Name="Image"></Image>-->
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

and inside my MainWindow.xaml.cs file i would like to edit the 'PlayButton' Visibility, but i can't seem to access it?

What is the correct way of accessing components like this?

Kind Regards - Corey.

Comment: Are you using MVVM? If you are this would be relatively trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The "PlayButton" resides inside a DataTemplate for the DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate, which means that you will see one "PlayButton" for each row of the table.

So, the window can't have a "PlayButton" property to access the button, since there are many instances of it.

Usually if you have to control the Visibility of that button, you will have to do it by Binding.

In addition, since the DataGrid uses by default EnableColumnVirtualization and EnableRowVirtualization, a single instance of the button can be reused when you scroll the grid elements, so the button has to be able to match the cell content only by using the data present in that row.

For example if the grid displays 10 rows, when you scroll down by one row, the visual components used to show the first row, which goes out of sight, will be reused to show the eleventh row. So any change you could have made to the PlayButton of the first row, will remain in the eleventh one, unless you change it again.

Another advice I can give you is to not use a Grid, if you can, inside a celltemplate of a column because the Grid is quite heavy to render, and assuming that the grid could show at the same time dozens of rows, the redering could be very slow.
I think that in this case it could be better to use a CellTemplateSelector to show only a PlayButton or a PauseButton, each one on its own DataTemplate, basing on the content of the row, or to use a single button with a Style responding to DataTriggers that changes the appearance of the button itself.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use a `DataTrigger` to toggle visibility :

```
<Button x:Name="PauseButton" ...>

    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <!-- Set Default Value here, not in Button Tag -->
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />

            <!-- Use Trigger to update value based on a conditional statement -->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>

    ...
</Button>
```

[Formentz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46056860/302677) is correct that the actual `Button` object is hard to use because it is not individually created for each row. Instead, only the visible rows are created, and the `.DataContext` behind each row changes as you scroll through. If you want to toggle the Visibility of the button, it needs to be based off a databound property so it updates as users scroll through the rows.